Can we connect Sybase database with Apache Impala?
I want to connect Sybase database with impala, is impala support sybase via jdbc or odbc connection? or need to use external connectors or drivers to connect sybase with impala?
I am trying to find, is the support is available to connect sybase with impala

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
